# Add exclusion on a pom.xml file if condition is true

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, integration-testing, pom.xml

I'm working on a pom.xml file where I want to exclude a file if condition is set to true, if not, i won't be excluded. I tried this using profiles but it does not work, how can I achieve this?

EDIT: Here is my profile in pom.xml. The idea for this is when I throw a mvn install, depending on my profile condition I will skip or execute some Cucumber/.feature files that I have. Right now I'm exluding the cucumber runner. When user does not want to exclude runner, mvn install will execute all tests (unit tests and cucumber tests). But when it is excluded, only unit tests are executed.

My idea is something like this:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>local</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/MyCucumberRunner.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <!-- <executions>
                     <execution>
                         <id>exclude-file</id>
                         <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                         <configuration>
                             <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                             <resources>
                                 <resource>
                                     <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                                     <excludes>
                                         <exclude>**/MyCucumberRunner.java</exclude>
                                     </excludes>
                                 </resource>
                             </resources>
                         </configuration>
                     </execution>
                 </executions> -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Are you using the default resource processing? If yes, what is the `<configuration>` tag for and why do you specify that `<outputDirectory>`? If no, how do you trigger the *resources:copy-resources* goal?

Comment: And two more questions: Does it work if you exclude the file unconditionally? Are you sure a *.java* file is a resource?

Comment: Please show the full pom file....

Comment: What condition do you want to use and why?

Comment: I would suggest to run the cucumber tests with maven-failsafe-plugin because in my opinion cucumber tests are more integration tests than unit tests.. Based on that you can simply select to run unit tests via `mvn clean test` or unit- and integration test (cucumber test) via `mvn clean verify` if you also define a profile to activate the execution of failsafe-plugin you can select it freely without any build-helper-maven-plugin only a single profile...

Answer (score 0):

So your actual goal seems to be to run only unit tests in one case and a full set with integration tests in another, and optionally run different Cucumber features based on conditions.

In order to not overcomplicate your Maven project (it will be a hard task to maintain it simple enough over the years), the correct way of doing so will be splitting the executions as [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) suggested using [`maven-failsafe-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) so that `mvn clean test` runs unit tests and `mvn clean verify` runs both unit and integration tests.

Moreover, you don't have to set up the plugins by yourself:

- `maven-surefire-plugin` [automatically includes](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) classes matching `**/Test*.java`, `**/*Test.java`, `**/*Tests.java`, `**/*TestCase.java` patterns;
- `maven-failsafe-plugin` [automatically includes](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) classes matching `**/IT*.java`, `**/*IT.java`, `**/*ITCase.java` patterns.

On top of that, this way you will also be able to run your builds using [`skipTests`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html) and [`skipITs`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html) properties to skip unit and integration tests, respectively. And these properties can also be added to Maven profiles.

After that, we can move to Cucumber itself. You can use tags and `cucumber.filter.tags` property (as well as [other options](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=java#options) such as `cucumber.features` property) to select which features you want to run, and this [can also be defined via Maven profiles](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/configuration/?lang=java#profiles):

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <cucumber.filter.tags>@dev and not @ignore</cucumber.filter.tags>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <properties>
            <cucumber.filter.tags>@qa</cucumber.filter.tags>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```